# How to replace three calls to a macrodef by only one?

Tags: ant, macrodef

How to replace three calls to "myMacro":

```
<myMacro value="value 1"/>
<myMacro value="value 2"/>
<myMacro value="value 3"/>
```

By only one call who would use a list of three elements: value 1, value 2, value 3

Comment: suggest you change the title to "how to replace three calls to macrodef with only one?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the [`For` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) from the 3rd party [Ant-Contribs tasks](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). It makes use of the Ant `MacroDef` task, so [combining this with your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643352/how-to-distribute-each-element-of-a-list-to-argument-of-a-task-ant) you could replace your macro and three macro calls with:

```
<for list="1,2,3" param="value">
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="cmd">
            <arg value="/c"/>
            <arg value="value @{value}"/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Within the sequential tag, why call the external shell/command prompt ? as opposed to: <myMacro value="value @{value}"/> ?

Comment: @PatriceM. Refer to the *combining this with your earlier question* link in my answer.